# Symfony logging in production ignores log level

Tags: php, logging, symfony1, symfony-1.4, error-logging

Related fragment from *factories.yml*:

```
prod:
  logger:
    class:   sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level:   err
      loggers: 
        sf_file_err:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: err
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
```

The problem: everything gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

This config works for me in all my projects.

```
prod:
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: err
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: err
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
```

Check [symfony-check.org](http://symfony-check.org/).

Answer (score 0):

That piece of config is fine. The problem must be somewhere else, quick brainstorm:

- look for projectFolder/**cache/frontend/prod/config/config_factories.yml.php**
- you should find sfAggregateLogger in it. Are the options OK?
- did you clear the prod cache (cc or even sudo rm ...)
- are you sure you're using spaces (not tabs) in the yml
- what did you put under **all:** ?
- make sure index.php **IS NOT** on debug mode

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, will go through once again, I also think it must be along the lines you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

```
prod:
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: debug
      loggers:
        sf_web_debug:
          class: sfWebDebugLogger
          param:
            level: debug
            condition:       %SF_WEB_DEBUG%
            xdebug_logging:  true
            web_debug_class: sfWebDebug
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: debug
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
```

Comment: As mentioned, the problem was that everything got logged although the error level was defined so unfortunately the above fragment doesn't deliver.